# Integrate apple login functionality in android without firebase

Tags: android

In my android app, I would like to integrate login with apple in my android app, I have seen [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/apple) regarding this, but they used firebase . Is there any way I can integrate apple login in my android app without using firebase.

Comment: Did you find a solution ? I'm stuck with firebase and I going to find an alternative method :)